# Can I get the current price of my app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a way to get the current price of the app from code? I found some things related to in-app purchases, but I'm looking for the price of the app itself.

Comment: Reasonable question, please show research effort.

Comment: You don't already know what that is?

Comment: djechlin -- I looked at some of your Stackoverflow questions to see what you are looking for regarding showing research effort. I'm not sure how you wish that to be shown as it's not in any of your own questions.

Robert -- I do, it's for reporting purposes using an analytics library. The price can change without a new release. I'd like to include it in the analytics.